# Mercurial Checkout without removing changes

Tags: mercurial

I am attempting to work with two separate branches. The first branch is a closer to deployment phase while the second branch is an early development phase. For one reason or another the second branch does not contain some of the developments from the first branch. When I attempt to checkout the first branch while working on the second branch I receive the following error:

```
abort: crossed branches (use 'hg merge' to merge or use 'hg update -c' to discard changes)
```

Now my problem is I don't want to get rid of the second branch or really edit it in anyway. When are my options, am I missing some fundamental fact with Mercurial?

Answer (score 1):

You need to either commit your changes or otherwise save them (e.g. with [`hg shelve`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension)) before checking out a new branch.

Mercurial (and most CVSes AFAIK) doesn't save the state of the working directory until you commit the changes, so switching branches effectively discards anything you haven't commited. You can work around this with the `hg shelve` extension, or by having one working copy for each branch you're working on.